# codelite code auto-formatter

Tags: c++, ide

I installed **Codelite** today and writing some C++. However the code auto-formatter doesn't seem to work. I went to keyboard shortcuts and I can see it should by default be set to CTRL+I. I suspect I need the plugin, because I can see this in keyboard shortcuts window:

[image]

I don't have any plugins installed currently, which I can see in plugin manager. There are some plugins mentioned on the official website, but nothing about formatter plugin. Any idea where I can find this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

I ended up installing codelite-plugins package from Ubuntu repository

```
sudo apt-get install codelite-plugins
```

I wanted to avoid this, because it has a lot of plugins I will not use. I can disable them in plugin manager, but I don't like installing stuff I don't need.

Here is a full list of plugins you get with the package (02 Mar 2019):

[image]

---

Also...

For those of you who are more advantageous, have a look [HERE](https://github.com/eranif/codelite). Official Codelite Github page has the app source and plenty of plugins. You can compile everything yourself and most likely choose what you want/need. I was too lazy to do it though...

Enjoy, hope this helps somebody.